# C# Google AnalyticsReporting v4 API - analyticsreporting function not found in Google Example Snippet

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Using this [code snippet from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples) I'm presented with this error. I can't figure out what I'm going wrong since I copy-pasted the snippet and installed the API trough nuget.

***CS0103 - The name 'analyticsreporting' does not exist in the current context on line 50.***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;


namespace GoogleAnalytics
{
    internal class Analytics
    {
        public Analytics(Dictionary<string, dynamic> analyticsConfig)
        {
            try
            {

                // Content here
                Console.WriteLine("Hello from Google Analytics. Starting..");

                // Create the DateRange object.
                DateRange dateRange = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2016-02-02", EndDate = "2016-01-01" };

                // Create the Metrics object.
                Metric sessions = new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" };

                //Create the Dimensions object.
                Dimension browser = new Dimension { Name = "ga:browser" };

                // Create the ReportRequest object.
                ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
                {
                    ViewId = "my_view_id_here",
                    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
                    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { browser },
                    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { sessions }
                };

                List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
                requests.Add(reportRequest);

                // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
                GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

                // Call the batchGet method.
                GetReportsResponse response = analyticsreporting.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All those samples assume you have already set up [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization) for your desired [client library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries). There are hello world examples in [PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php), [Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py), etc. If your favorite language is missing always look at the client library documentation first to get started

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I found that answer and posted it bellow. My suggestion would be that the example snippet would include a comment of some kind so that the developer knows that the code is incomplete. There are some other Google API examples around that have those comments so the user knows that it needs more work to get tru the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution tho I think it can be better documented by the Google team than it is now. The following code demonstrates one working c# example with oauth2.

```
 private static async Task Run()
    {
        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = Settings.Default.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = Settings.Default.ClientSecret
            },
            new[] {AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly},
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

        var service = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "GAReportDownloader",
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        // Content here
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from Google Analytics. Starting..");

        // Create the DateRange object.
        var dateRange = new DateRange {StartDate = "2017-07-01", EndDate = "2017-07-10"};

        // Create the Metrics object.
        var sessions = new Metric {Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions"};

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        var browser = new Dimension {Name = "ga:browser"};

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
        {
            ViewId = "YOURVIEWIDHERE",
            DateRanges = new List<DateRange> {dateRange},
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension> {browser},
            Metrics = new List<Metric> {sessions}
        };

        var requests = new List<ReportRequest> {reportRequest};

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        var getReport = new GetReportsRequest {ReportRequests = requests};

        // Call the batchGet method.
        var response = service.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```